# Django 'DIRS': [] in settings.py TEMPLATES causes "TemplateDoesNotExist" Error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django version 2.1.2 with python 3.6.

I created two django projects (test01 & test02) by CMD.
Both of the projects are under the same folder.
Test01 executes normally, while test02 raises TemplateDoesNotExist error.  [image]

I've found a solution for the latter that is hard coding the address of templates in settings.py:

'DIRS': [r'C:\django\test02\accounts\templates']

However, another project can run normally even leaving this list as blank [].

The structures of both projects are the same:
[image]

Can anyone give a suggestion that can fix the problem in test02 without hard coding the address of templates in test02?

Comment: Please post the `settings.py` for the one which is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may notice a built-in Django variable named `BASE_DIR`, it represents your root project, so you don't need to hard code the absolute path.

Add this in settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # codes...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Register all your apps, and Django will look for any files inside a folder named `templates` as you mentioned in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')`

Comment: Thanks, I am following the Django polls app and at last on customizing admin, have to change the DIRS on that I was putting the 'DIRS' = [BASE_DIR / 'templates')], and that is showing me TypeError, know I understand why I got that problem. Thanks once again. The full error which I got = 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Let create a folder called `test01App` in template and create `base.html` on it.
Then you can call `test01App/base.html` in response.
***BACKEND*** is default of Django and you have to create folder `templates`.
You can customize where it stores template in other place in `DIRS`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, './cuong')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```